# ASP.NET C# CSS/Boostrap overlapping

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net

Needed some assistance, [image]
Please look at the picture below, as you can see, When I click the input which has calender, the calender pop up inside the table and it generates a scroll bar which I have to scroll down to see the bottom calender, how do I make sure it is send to front which will show the entire calender outside that table ?

Thanks!

Calender CSS: https://github.com/benitolopez/hotel-datepicker/tree/master/dist

```
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Shopping cart</h4>
                    </div>
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                          <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                                                <td class="text-center"></td>
                                <td class="text-center">Image</td>
                                <td class="text-left">Product Name</td>
                                <td class="text-left">Rental Period</td>
                                <td class="text-left">Rental Rate</td>

                                <td class="text-left">Deposit Amount</td>
                                <td class="text-right">Total</td>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="text-center"><p></p><button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove" class="btn btn-danger" onClick=""><i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i></button></td>

                                <td class="text-center"><a href="product.html"><img width="60px" src="image/demo/shop/product/E4.jpg" alt="Xitefun Causal Wear Fancy Shoes" title="Xitefun Causal Wear Fancy Shoes" class="img-thumbnail"></a></td>
                                <td class="text-left"><a href="product.html">Emasa rumas gacem</a></td>
                                <td class="text-left"><div class="input-group btn-block" style="min-width: 100px;">

    <form method="POST" action="checkout.html">

    <input type="text" name="input-id" id="input-id" value="" class="form-control">

    </form>



                                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                                    <button type="submit" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Update" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-refresh"></i></button>
                                    </span></div></td>
                                <td class="text-right">$114.35</td>
                                <td class="text-right">$114.35</td>
                                <td class="text-right">$114.35</td>                                 
                              </tr>
                            </tbody>
                            <tfoot>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="text-right" colspan="1"><strong>Meeting Location:</strong></td>
                                <td class="text-left" colspan="6">$93.73</td>

                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="text-right" colspan="6"><strong>Total Amount Payable:</strong></td>
                                <td class="text-right">$121.85</td>
                              </tr>
                            </tfoot>
                          </table>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
```

Update:
I removed the "position" in the css of the calender and it now looks like this.
Everytime the calender pop up, the table will adjust/squeeze to fit the calender, how to make sure that calender just shows without changing the size of the table?

Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Code..........?

Comment: yes code please

Comment: Thanks! just updated

Comment: @SharavnanKv UpdateD!

Comment: @Imad Updated, thanks. Hope its enough. Do you need the CSS code as well ?

Comment: Is the enclosing container for the Calendar has any height set explicitly? try increasing the height of enclosing tag (div or td)

Comment: @Sujith Thanks for the reply, do you mean increase the height of enclosing tag? Thanks

Comment: @CarmenC Yes. Along with that also check the positioning/orientation of the Calendar.

Comment: @Sujith When you said calender, should I check the html side or css?

Comment: @CarmenC Did you try changing the height as I mentioned in first comment? if so, did it work? Calendar might have got some css applied based on the Calendar settings in the JS, so observe the css of rendered calendar in the browser.

Comment: @Sujith Hi!! Managed to solve that problem, I updated my post, could you please check my post above again? got new prob :D Thanks! <3

Comment: @CarmenC :-) Try applying position: relative or absolute and try to apply top/left with some pixels like :  position: relative;  left: 30px; . I am not very good at this. But I know that if you can change the position property it should work for you.

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: @Sujith Still cant :<